# Android NDK: Poor native code debugging performance - any solutions?

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

I am debugging Android NDK application on a physical device, and debugging performance is extremely poor. Specifically - stepping code from line to line takes 13 sec. Any ideas why is it so and is it possible to improve this time?

***Update:*** I have noticed that on Ubuntu 12.04 running in VMWare virtual machine on Windows 7 one step takes 11-13 seconds, while on native (non-virtual) Fedora one step takes 7-8 seconds on the same PC with the same device being debugged. 8 is better than 13, but still very slow.

Comment: Can you say more about the device and how you connect to it?

Comment: @gfour I had troubled with the same issue with different device from different vendors (Samsung/htc/lg). It does not a issue related to devices

Comment: @gfour: I have tried Acer A500 (Android 3.1), some HTC phones (2.3) connected via USB or Wi-Fi - same thing.